# How can I clear a BIOS password on my HP 15-1272wm laptop

Tags: bios

The BIOS password was installed by a scammer when my friend called the number that popped up on her screen. She provided them personal info and now she is locked out of her own computer. I have already removed the CMOS battery to no avail. This looks like a stringent password. After 3 failed login attempts this code displays, 76263797. Can someone generate an override/master password?
Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Assuming this is a BIOS password, you must contact an authorized HP Service Center or HP Support directly and be capable of showing proof of ownership, there could and likely will be a service charge and it may have to be sent in. The BIOS/UEFI startup password cannot be cleared by "normal" means. There are some BIOS password unlock tools that can be purchased on the "gray" market (there are no free ones), but I cannot recommend any due the questionable legality of them.

Comment: Your master password is  69141319, record this  somewhere in case they are locked out again. I will delete this comment after you have responded and recorded the password I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the battery it will reset the bios. You can reset your bios using the jumper on the mainboard, too. The effect of this second method should be the same.

If the laptop is still locked after bios reset, it can be caused by a locked harddrive or a locked operating system. Try using a live system like ubuntu or test another harddrive.

There are ways to lock your laptop by flashing another bios to your mainboard. In this case I don't know a solution except for changing the mainboard.

---

**edited**

I found another solution. Look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/reset-bios-on-hp-probook-4530s)

Comment: "I have already removed the CMOS battery to no avail." ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe your harddrive or your operating system is locked. If there is no spash screen after startup your bios is probably flashed. I've searched in the internet for another solution. Look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1108228/reset-bios-on-hp-probook-4530s)

Comment: I'm not the OP. I was pointing out that OP has already done what was suggested in the answer.