# Bios Password remove

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, passwords

I have a laptop that came with preinstalled windows and everything, it used to work through VPN to connect remote servers. Laptop was not in our ownership until now. But we needed to reinstall OS. But there is problem. Laptop have a bios password. Reset CMOS is NOT WORKING! 
There is no way to reset password with standard methods. What i think is that bios was flashed with this password already set as it was part of a communication with goverment software. Company that used to maintain this, refused to give us bios password. 
So now we have Laptop that can't be used because there is no way to change booting settings so we can install new bought WIN10.
Maybe you will have idea what do to?

EDIT1: Model of laptop is HP Probook 455 G2

EDIT2: one more time, i already tried all the basic methods, as website that can calculate master password, or removing CMOS battery for 2 days! THESE METHODS ARE NOT WORKING!

Comment: I don't know if your laptop model is the same as this one but this was answered before and it might help you: <https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/remove-bios-password-for-hp-probook-4530s-reset-bios>

Answer (score 0):

There is a website called [bios-pw.org](https://bios-pw.org/) that is able to calculate the master BIOS password from your device identifier.
With this calculated master password you can login into the BIOS settings menu and reset the actual password or modify other settings.

HP devices are supported as well.