# How to reset the BIOS password of HP ProBook 6360b

Tags: bios, passwords

How do I reset the BIOS password of an HP ProBook 6360b? 
I tried these tricks:

- I removed the CMOS battery and left it for 7 days.
- I short circuited the jumper wires.

But nothing happened.

Comment: Though model is different but you may try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/remove-bios-password-for-hp-probook-4530s-reset-bios). [Here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/HP-ProBook-6560b-BIOS-password-reset/td-p/5960686) are few steps from HP official website.

Comment: You might want to try HP Probook/Elitebook BIOS Password Reset Utility [here](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/hp-probook-elitebook-bios-password-reset-utility.49497/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to take it to a authorized HP assistance with the invoice I guess.