# How to reset bios password of hp probook 6560b

Tags: windows-10, bios, hp-pavilion, smc

I have tried with SMC.BIN file but it says SMC COMMMAND FAILURE. This smc.bin file wasted my $15 but not worked and i also removed CMOS for 1 hrs but nothing happened. Tried Some other utility using windows 10 OS but nothing worked. Is there any way to reset bios password without risk.

Comment: there should be a clear cmos jumper somewhere on the motherboard that you have to use.

Comment: The BIOS password on most modern laptops cannot be reset[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/remove-bios-password-for-hp-probook-4530s-reset-bios).  Removing the CMOS battery on a modern laptop does not actually reset the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do need a physical programmer device (the most commonly used is CH341A) for that. You have to dump your BIOS chip contents, then wipe out (overwrite with `FF`s) the `VSS$` region of the chip.

As a side effect, your motherboard information, serial IDs, SKUs and UUID will also be wiped out, but then you can use `FSMC.bin` included with manufacturing preparation toolkit (along with `wndmifit` and other related tools) to enter the MPM and write back those information.

**Disclaimer:** this operation is **potentially dangerous for your hardware**. Wrong polarity of the programmer clip around the BIOS chip can destroy it, also wrong voltages set on the programmer can destroy the chip too. **Always use extreme caution tinkering with the sensitive motherboard electronics!**