# Recover BIOS password of HP Pavilion 14 G1 laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords, password-recovery

I have a client who has given me a laptop which has an administrator password at startup, so I can't get into the BIOS. My client doesn't remember the password and needs his computer. I already tried to remove the CMOS battery and effectively when I start it tells me that the BIOS has been reset, but when I press Enter to reboot it once again asks me for the password. I also couldn't find the backup password on the internet. Is there any way to reset this password?

**Edit:**

Following [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1108228/remove-bios-password-for-hp-probook-4530s-reset-bios?rq=1) i tried to **short circuit** two pins but it seems the datasheets i found for the bios chip isn´t the right one. [Here is](https://www.pjrc.com/store/w25q64fv.pdf) the data sheet i found. I tried to short circuit pins **4 & 5** and **5 & 6** but nothing happened. The picture shows the chip i found The description on the chip i guess would be **winbond 25Q64FVSIQ 1647** I would appreciate any thougts arround this matter.

[image: Bios Chip]

Comment: enter the wrong password 3 times, if it output's a code post it in the comments.

Comment: hi, the code is [i 71723528]

Comment: Try 64681508, if it works save this as it is the master password for that specific laptop

Comment: it didn´t work either. I have tried literally more than a hundred master passwords

Comment: I thought that, so you are out of luck on recovering the password as I posted below. Has the client contacted HP Support?

Comment: i´ll be calling him next monday to tell him the bad news. I didn´t give him so much hope though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reset this power-on password. Modern machines prevent this. The client might possibly succeed calling HP Support - that is about all the client can do. Otherwise there is no solution.